# updating specific component inside v-for loop - Vue js - laravel 5.6

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I am struggling to find a solution for this problem: I am using Vue.js with Laravel 5.6 and fetching items then displaying them using Vue.

When clicking on the **bid on this item** button, i would like to update the data inside that < li > list item, such as the  element with the **ref** property **totalBids** using the **bidOnThis(id)** method

**Edited:** updated the code to reflect **ref** property and the updated but still wrong **bidOnThis(id)** function

```
<template>
<div>
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-4" v-for="auction in auctions" :key="auction.id">
            <span>{{ auction.name }} {{ auction.id }}</span><br />
            <span>{{ auction.bid_time }}</span><br />
            <span ref="totalBids">{{ auction.total_bids }}</span><br />
            <span ref="user">{{ auction.username }}</span><br />
            <button ref="newBid" @click="bidOnThis(auction.id)">Bid on this item</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            auctions: [],
            newBid: '',
            totalBids: ''
        };
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/auctions').then(result => {
                this.auctions = result.data
            })

    },
    methods: {
        bidOnThis(id) {
            axios.post('/auctions', { id: id });
            this.auction.totalBids = '100';
        }
    }
};
```

this is where I am at, but doesn't work either

```
bidOnThis(id) {
            axios.post('/auctions', { id: id });
            this.auctions.$refs.totalBids.innerHTML = '100';
        }
```

Comment: v-model is for input, why is it used on `span`,`button`?

Comment: i used it as i thought i was a way to reference an element, what else would be used to refference?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: thanks, so i would use something like: <child-component ref="child-{{ auction.id }}"></child-component>?

Comment: I am still not quite grasping how i would apply this into the function

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching around, i found this: [Better method of using refs inside a v-for based on object](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/better-method-of-using-refs-inside-a-v-for-based-on-object/21352)

and have updated my code using **key, index** in my v-for loop, then referencing the **key** through the method
 allowing me to use the **key** to reference the correct element

`bidOnThis(auction.id, key)`

and

`this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML = parseInt(this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML) + 1 ;`

See full code below:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1 ref="testing">0</h1>
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-4" v-for="(auction, key, index) in auctions" :key="auction.id">
            <span>{{ auction.name }} ({{ auction.id }})</span><br />
            <span>{{ auction.bid_time }}</span><br />
            <span ref="totalBids">{{ auction.total_bids }}</span><br />
            <span ref="user">{{ auction.username }}</span><br />
            <button ref="newBid" @click="bidOnThis(auction.id, key)">Bid on this item</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            auctions: [],
            newBid: '',
            totalBids: '',
            testing: ''
        };
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/auctions').then(result => {
                this.auctions = result.data
            })

    },
    methods: {
        bidOnThis(id, key) {
            axios.post('/auctions', { id: id });
            this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML = parseInt(this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML) + 1 ;
        }
    }
};
```